# How to start a process instance in jbpm 5.3 from external source?

Tags: jbpm

After successfully login to my application i want to run a jBPM process instances by clicking a button or image.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a link to what? 
In order to start a process you should use the jBPM APIs, if you have a web application in JSP for example you will need to create a servlet which use the jBPM APIs. You have all the flexibility to do it in the way you want.

Cheers

Comment: I found a class file in gwt-console-server, FormProcessingFacade.class which contains method startProcessWithUI(HttpServletRequest request, String definitionId, MultipartFormDataInput payload) 
what paremeters should i pass in this method ?